# Base number of HTML table rows on number of SQL results

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to make a table based on a result from an SQL query in PHP. I know that if my query returned 2 results I could use

```
echo '<table>
      <tr>
         <th>User</th>
         <th>Answer</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>$row[0]['username']</td>
         <td>$row[0]['answer']</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>$row[1]['username']</td>
         <td>$row[1]['answer']</td>
      </tr>
```

But how do I go about this if I don't know how many results will be returned

EDIT:

I have used a loop as advised but the results appear underneath the table instead of inside. Only the table headers are inside. Any ideas?

```
echo '<table class="collabtable">
              <tr>
              <th>User</th>
              <th>Answer</th>
              </tr>';
        foreach($rows as $row){
            if (isset($row['collabans'])){
                echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$row['username'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['collabans'].'</td>
                      </tr>';
            }
        echo '</table>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: use a loop.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use loop. See below.

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Answer</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($rows as $row) { 
          if (isset($row['collabans'])){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['answer']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } 
        } ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helps but am still stuck on syntax. I have edited my answer to show where I'm at now

Comment: Close the table after close the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all results of your query result as below:

```
if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        <tr>
             <td>$row['username']</td>
             <td>$row['answer']</td>
        </tr>      
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps but am still stuck on syntax. I have edited my answer to show where I'm at now

Comment: echo '</table>'; should be after second closing bracket